# ExtJS 3 Why not sort all columns?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have created several columns and when ordering them ascending and descending there are two concrete (auxiNombre and paciNombre) that the sortable property does not work. In all other columns it works. What can it be?

```
var columnsIncidencias = [
    {
        header: this.i18n.gridColumnId,
        dataIndex: 'id',
        defaultValue : -1,
        sortable:true,
        hidden: false
    },{
        header: this.i18n.gridColumnAuxiliar,
        dataIndex: 'auxiNombre',
        sortable:true,
        hidden: false
    },{
        header: this.i18n.gridColumnPaciente,
        dataIndex: 'paciNombre',
        sortable:true,
        hidden: false
    },{
        header: this.i18n.gridColumnDesc,
        dataIndex: 'inteMotivo',
        sortable:true,
        hidden: false
    },{        
        header: this.i18n.gridColumnFecha,
        dataIndex: 'inteFechaCrea',
        //width: 4,
        sortable: true,
        hidden: false,
        hideable: true,
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y')
    },{
        header: this.i18n.gridColumnEstado,
        dataIndex: 'sene1Estado.valoNombre',
        sortable:true,
        //width: 50,
        hidden: false
    },{
        header: this.i18n.gridColumnCriticidad,
        dataIndex: 'sene1Criticidad.valoNombre',
        sortable:true,
        //width: 40,
        hidden: false
    },{
        header: this.i18n.gridColumnTipo,
        dataIndex: 'sene1Tipo.valoNombre',
        sortable:true,
        //width: 70,
        hidden: false
    }];
```

The DataType is:

```
var recordIncidencia = Ext.data.Record.create([
        {name: 'id', type: 'int', defaultValue : -1, mapping : 'inteId'},
        {name: 'inteMotivo', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'inteEstadoId', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'sene1Estado.valoNombre', type: 'string', mapping: 'inteEstado'},
        {name: 'sene1Tipo.valoNombre', type: 'string', mapping: 'inteTipo'},
        {name: 'auxiNombre', type: 'string', mapping: 'auxiNombre'},
        {name: 'paciNombre', type: 'string', mapping: 'paciNombre'},
        {name: 'sene1Criticidad.valoNombre', type: 'string', mapping: 'inteCriticidad'},
        {name: 'inteFechaCrea',type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd/m/Y'}

    ]);

    var storeIncidencias = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad : false,
        url                 : ctx + '/incidenTeleasisGrid.do',
        baseParams          : { auxId: this.auxId},
        root                : 'results',
        id                  : 'inteId',
        totalProperty       : 'totalCount', 
        fields              : recordIncidencia,
        remoteSort          : true, 
        sortInfo            : {field: 'inteFechaCrea', direction: "DESC"}
    });
```

The image shows the data of the GRID that I have to order. What is rounding in black are the columns that fail.

[image]

Comment: What is the type of data that comes for those two columns data indexes? Also can you please provide a fiddle with same type of some hardcoded static data that you are having to look into this issue?

Comment: Hello Harshit,the type of data is added it in the code,thanks you

Comment: Can you provide an example fiddle for this? because need to try some changes

Comment: @HarshitShah Is the image that I put on you? Or you need something else. I did not quite understand what you needed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: First of all, there are other columns also like description and Estado where sorting is not working. I think there is something wrong in grid definition or someplace else. Can you provide a example fiddle for this to recreate the issue?